# npm Error: Cannot find module 'core-util-is'

Tags: react-native, npm

When I run

```
npm -v, npm install and npm install --save react-native-voice
```

this error appears:

```
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'core-util-is'

    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:67:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

Comment: It works on my computer:
npm install react-native-voice
+ react-native-voice@0.2.6
added 1 package in 2.375s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solution solve my problem

1- i run this command

```
rm -rf /usr/local/{lib/node{,/.npm,_modules},bin,share/man}/npm*
```

2- i install node.js again

3- i run

```
npm install
```

and now every thing is ok.

Answer (score 2):

Try running npm update and then npm install again. That worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem, too: when executing `npm install` on a project depending on the sharp image processing module I've got the same `Error: Cannot find module 'core-util-is'`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue, but finally figured it why this is happening...

**Solution**
  Remove npm and npm-cache folder from users/yourName/Appdata/Roaming.

then remove node completely from your computer.

restart

Now, reinstall node.js using msi installer .

done.

Answer (score -1):

Delete the npm-cache folder from local

Uninstall node

Restart

Re-install node