# REACT Error: Cannot find module 'core-util-is'

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npx

I´m stuck creating an react app.
I have tried npx create-react-app my app, but it doesn´t work. Now I get this "Cannot find module 'core-utils-is', previously I fixed another problem with another module. So, that I suspect that I am in a bug.
I think the best solution is to start from cero. But I´m not sure how can I uninstall an reinstall all that I need without breaking all (nodejs, npm...).
I enclose the image of my console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pCGr.png)

> $ npx create-react-app my-app internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
> throw err;   ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'core-util-is' Require stack:
>
> - C:\Users\ILC\node_modules\hyperquest\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_duplex.js
> - C:\Users\ILC\node_modules\hyperquest\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_transform.js
> - C:\Users\ILC\node_modules\hyperquest\node_modules\readable-stream\transform.js
> - C:\Users\ILC\node_modules\hyperquest\node_modules\through2\through2.js
> - C:\Users\ILC\node_modules\hyperquest\index.js
> - C:\Users\ILC\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js
> - C:\Users\ILC\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js
>   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
>   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
>   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
>   at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
>   at Object. (C:\Users\ILC\node_modules\hyperquest\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_duplex.js:39:12)
>   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
>   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
>   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
>   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19) {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [
>   'C:\Users\ILC\node_modules\hyperquest\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_duplex.js',
>   'C:\Users\ILC\node_modules\hyperquest\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js',
>   'C:\Users\ILC\node_modules\hyperquest\node_modules\readable-stream\transform.js',
>   'C:\Users\ILC\node_modules\hyperquest\node_modules\through2\through2.js',
>   'C:\Users\ILC\node_modules\hyperquest\index.js',
>   'C:\Users\ILC\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js',
>   'C:\Users\ILC\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js'   ] } Thank you

Comment: hello try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59205822/14522591)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to update npm with `npm update` and see if that fixes it, and if not you can try these steps.

If you've previously installed `create-react-app` globally via `npm install -g create-react-app`, it is recommend you uninstall the package using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` or `yarn global remove create-react-app` to ensure that `npx` always uses the latest version.

You may also want to `cd` into a directory that you want to host your programs. I tend to put all my programs into a folder in `c:\Users\<Username>\Documents\github`. It looks like your `node_modules` is trying to install directly to your user home directory.

Once you are in the directory of choice to build your app and you have removed the global installations you can try running these commands.
`npx create-react-app my-app`
`cd my-app`
`npm start`

[Create React App - Getting Started](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/)

Edit: If that works for you, then you may also want to go back to `C:\Users\ILC` and remove your `node_modules` folder and any other remnant files such as `package.json` that don't belong in that folder.

Comment: Thank you, Travis. I´ve follow your suggestions: I tried npm update, then I´ve npm uninstall -g create-react-app, I created a new directory and cd into my new directory and npx create-react-app my-app and I become the same error. I think I miss a step.

Comment: Of course! If this solved your problem, please remember to mark this solution as accepted. And have a great day!

Comment: Are you on Mac, Windows or Linux? You may just have to reinstall npm.

Comment: I am on Windows.

Comment: Ah, super easy then. [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) download page

Comment: Anytime! Have a great day!